# Need to block all personal info like url , email, messenger ids, telephone etc using php

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex or functions that will block user to post there private information . I have used regex but they by by pass it using patterns  like email dot com , or [dot] or (doe). I need to block all there personal info like email, url , chat ids and telephone numbers . I have found few patterns  which my members used most

"www, @, .com, (at), dot, (dot), ++, e-mail, Email, website, msn, Tel, Yahoo, hotmail, gmail, hotmail(dot)com, gmail(dot)com, http://, EMAIL, G-mail, , WWW, .COM, skype, tel, yahoo, yahoo(dot)com, G-Talk, gtalk, *com, www*, Fax, Google Talk, Web, "

Answer (score 1):

No matter how many patterns you will have, they will find a new one to get around your protection. There's no sure way to do what you want to do.

Comment: but we also have to keep trying , as they are doing

Comment: Actually, no. You should instead come up with a way of fixing the problem for both parties instead of trying to enforce these (impossible) filtering mechanisms.